# Angular Js Simple Form not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Started today learning angular js, and right now i've been for half an hour trying to find why is it not calling the scope currectly.
Is it codepen problem? I did a previous one, and it worked fine.
If you could be of help and explain me what's wrong that would be awesome.
Thank you

Code is also on https://codepen.io/pars3c/pen/wdbBmE?editors=1010

HTML CODE

```
     <div ng-app="info-app" ng-controller="infocontroller">
     <p>Nome <input type="text" ng-model="nome"></p>
     <p>Idade <input type="text" ng-model="idade"></p>
     <p>Morada <input type="text" ng-model="morada"></p>

     <p>Toda a minha info: {{nome+" "+idade+" "+morada}}</p>
     </div>
```

Javascript

```
    var app = angular.module ("info-app", []);
    app.controller = ('infocontroller', function ($scope){
    $scope.nome = "Aderito";
    $scope.idade = "25";
    $scope.morada = "Alcantarilha";

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this

```
 app.controller('infocontroller', function ($scope){
  $scope.nome = "Aderito";
  $scope.idade = "25";
  $scope.morada = "Alcantarilha";

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro. I feel ashamed of my clumsiness right now

Comment: @wydtron: Its good to look your code properly rather than moving to SO after half an hour of struggle.

Comment: I know, i confused the sintax, and thought it was right for some reason

Answer (score 0):

In order to learn `Angular`, you should put your traditional javascript programming aside... I suggest you to do the below:

1. browse the following URL and try to read it a few times before doing anything: [Angular 2 Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)
2. Afterwards, read Angular2 Cli and understand what it is: [Angular2 Cli](https://cli.angular.io/)
3. Then use a code editor `(e.g. Visual Studio Code)` to do your programming.

Alright, once you are done with the above, you will know how to use Bootstrap to generate your forms and access them via Angular components.

I would suggest to take your time and before getting your hands on the code, read as much as you can. Afterwards, your will learn how quick you can do things in Angular.

Comment: It would be good if you will start following the convention of differentiating between different versions. Dont mix *Angular* (v2+) with *Angularjs* (v1.x) while writing or explaining things to people.
Hope this will help u :)